# Spotify embed iframe not loading in IE11

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-11, spotify

I am using iframe tag and adding Spotify playlist url in src, see the example below:

```
<iframe class="myspotify-iframe" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/3p5lcgvL0wxDeu32u3prL1" title="Spotify playlist" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media">
</iframe>
```

above code is working fine in chrome, firefox & safari. But the playlist is not loading in IE11.

Any suggestion how this issue can be fixed ?

Comment: As you can see that IE is not supported by Spotify. If you think that it can answer your question. I suggest you please mark the helpful suggestion as an accepted answer.  It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

That website may no longer be compatible with IE11.

Don't make your websites compatible with IE11, or else you won't be able to use recent web standards without a lot of hacks. IE11 was released in 2013, 7 years before 2020.

Answer (score 0):

I try to check the Spotify official docs to check the browser support.

I come to know by visiting this [link](https://support.spotify.com/us/using_spotify/getting_started/webplayer/) that Spotify web player supported by Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera, and Safari browser.

So it looks like the IE browser is not supported and this is the reason that your playlist is not loading in the IE browser.

The issue is not related to an iframe. If you directly try to open the page in the IE browser then you can notice that it will show an error in the console.

I suggest trying to use the new [MS Edge browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) can help you to avoid the issue.